# Android Socket TCP Dataloss

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp, ftp

I am unable to transmit an entire file using WiFi-Direct. The file sender is indicating that the entire file has been copied over to the socket output stream. The file receiver is only receiving roughly half of the file.

I looked at the contents of both the original file and the contents of the file storing the received data, and found the receiver is only receiving pieces of the original file. For example, it would receive bytes 0-100, and then it would jump to byte 245-350.

**Why is the receiver only receiving bits and pieces of the file, rather than the entire file?**

#### File Receiving Logic

```
    private class FileReceiveThread(val channel: Channel) : TransmissionThread() {
        private var mFileName: String = ""
        private var mFileSize: Long = 0L
        private var mBytesReceivedTotal = 0L

        override fun run() {
            try {
                Timber.d("File receive thread running: fileSize=$mFileSize, fileName=$mFileName")
                val outputFile = File.createTempFile("file", "")
                val fileOutput = outputFile.outputStream()
                val channelInput = channel.getInputStream().unwrap()

                val inputBuffer = ByteArray(FILE_TX_BUFFER_SIZE)
                var bytesReceived = channelInput.read(inputBuffer)

                while (bytesReceived > 0) {
                    fileOutput.write(inputBuffer)
                    mBytesReceivedTotal += bytesReceived
                    Timber.d("Received $mBytesReceivedTotal total bytes")
                    bytesReceived = channelInput.read(inputBuffer)
                }

                onTransmitComplete?.invoke()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }

        fun start(filename: String, size: Long) {
            mFileName = filename
            mFileSize = size
            start()
        }
    }
```

#### File Sending Logic

```
    private class FileSendThread : TransmissionThread() {
        var mFile: File? = null
        var mOutputStream: OutputStream? = null

        override fun run() {
            if (mFile != null && mOutputStream != null) {
                val inputStream = mFile!!.inputStream()
                val channelStream = mOutputStream!!
                val buffer = ByteArray(FILE_TX_BUFFER_SIZE)

                var bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)
                var totalBytesRead = 0L + bytesRead

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    Timber.v("Read $bytesRead, total $totalBytesRead")
                    channelStream.write(buffer)
                    bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead
                }

                Timber.d("Wrote file to output stream")

                inputStream.close()

                Timber.d("No more data to send")
                onTransmitComplete?.invoke()
            } else Timber.d("Parameters null: file=$mFile")
        }

        fun start(file: File, stream: OutputStream) {
            mFile = file
            mOutputStream = stream
            start()
        }
    }
```

Comment: `while (mBytesReceivedTotal < mFileSize) ` How would the receiver at forehand know the size of the file? Very strange.

Comment: Missing: `fileOutput.close()`.

Comment: `Timber.v("Bytes received total: $mBytesReceivedTotal")` Well what did it print?

Comment: ```mFileSize``` is received outside of the thread, and is passed in. See the bottom of  FileSendThread. ```fileOutput``` is closed elsewhere.

As for the bytes received logging, it only prints the number of bytes received. It is consistently roughly half of the total file size. Indicating that the receiver only receives half of the file.

Comment: `mFileSize is received outside of the thread, ` That doe snot answer my question. Repeat: `How would the receiver at forehand know the size of the file? `.

Comment: I don’t understand how that doesn’t answer your question? Perhaps with a little more detail: I have a separate connection that I use to control a stream. On that controlling stream, I transmit information like the name of the file and the size of the file.

Comment: You send a file of more than 3MB. To debug what goes wrong i suggest you send a text file of about 1000 byes. Then it is very easy to see what you receive and what not. And how the amount of bytes differ. `Perhaps with a little more detail: ` Yes . Please. Your post lacks detail

Comment: Ok, but what could be causing the loss? That is what I am trying to determine. I am taking all the recommended actions for file transfer over sockets, yet I am only receiving half of the bytes that are being written from sender.

Comment: I do not understand your kotlin code because i do not know much of kotlin yet. But i wonder what that `unwrap()` means in `val channelInput = DataInputStream(channel.getInputStream().unwrap())`. Why a channelInput? What specifics does it? Isn't there a BufferedReader available?

Comment: What details does the post lack? I will get them. `unwrap()` is just a part of an abstraction that I created, similar to Rust's `Option<T>`.

Comment: Further i do not understand why you copy the `buffer` to yet another ByteArray. `fileOutput.write(inputBuffer.toByteArray())` Why not `   fileOutput.write(buffer);`

Comment: Sorry about the details... i mixed you up with another post that is about sockets too. Sorry.

Comment: I was experimenting, but at this point it doesn't matter. The fact that I am only receiving half of the expected bytes is a problem.

Comment: Yes. Will you do the test wit a 1000 bytes text file?

Comment: I can, but it will be a while before I get the chance to do so.

Comment: Ok. You use wifi direct. Did you test using wifi only?

Comment: Yes, I have only tested via WiFi.

Comment: Alright, I tested sending a 1KB file and was able to receive it fully. After doing so, I increase that to 1MB and started to get data loss. I decreased it to 512 KB and was able to receive the entire file again. I'm going to try chunking the file into 512 KB chunks, and sending those chunks one at a time with a delay between sending.

Comment: Hmmmm.. no good.

Comment: You are certainly not taking all the recommended actions here. This is all wrong. Use the standard Java copy loop at both ends, however it looks in Kotlin: `while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0) { out.write(buffer, 0, count); }`. Get rid of the data input streams and the other mad `while` conditions and all the second-guessing about how much you've read and written.

Comment: @user207421 I updated the code using your recommendations, however the problem still persists. What else could be causing the data loss?

Answer (score 1):

```
           while (inputStream.read(buffer) > 0) {
                channelStream.write(buffer)
            }
```

The read() will often not fill the complete buffer. Hence if you write the buffer then only as far as it is filled.

```
           var totalbytesread = 0;
           var nread;
           while ((nread = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                channelStream.write(buffer, 0, nread)
                totalbytesread += nread;
            }

           channelStream.close()';
```

Log the totalbytesread.
Your original code would have caused a bigger received file so there is something else to be discovered..

Comment: I am not receiving a bigger file, I am receiving a smaller file. The received file is roughly half of the file being sent. Here are the logs for receiving: [link](https://pastebin.com/eLVX43EY). Also, here are the logs for sending: [link](https://pastebin.com/sEk4VFzi),

Note: The receiving logs appear to be cut off, but they are not.

Comment: `channelStream.write(buffer, 0, nread)` Does that really write `nread' bytes? Isnt there a return value? `int nwritten =  channelStream.write(buffer, 0, nread)` ? They should be equal. Check.

Comment: Checked earlier, it does not!

Comment: Sorry but i dont know what you mean with is does not. Please be exact.

Comment: The `write(b byte[])` function does not return the number of bytes written. It is of return type `void`